# Ignore the array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a couple of arrays, and trying to achieve a way where I can load the data first and then i have an different array from which I need to add the price ignoring the han products.

What happening is the second array is ignoring its number of index values, as per number of han products skipping.

How do I can achieve this, by appending proper price values to my array by skipping the han products.

Example:

```
First Array : $scope.results = results[i];

Second Array : var nPrice = []; nPrice=response.data

for(var i=0;i<$scope.results.length;i++){
if($scope.results[i].type==“han”)
    console.log(“Han Product”);
}
else{
    $scope.results[i].cPrice = nPrice[i].curPrice;
}
```

Comment: show your real data of First & Second array

Comment: Could you make a working JS Fiddle or Plunkr for this?